# Name for gerund + past participle combination

Tags: grammar, conjugation, verb-construction

I've noticed that this passive verb construction is especially prevalent in English translations of Scandinavian and German literature. Is there a formal name for it?

Example: Being walked is my dog's favourite activity.

Comment: I'm not aware of a formal name for it. Syntactically, it is 'passive gerund-participial clause' functioning as subject. Like most non-finite clauses, it is subjectless, and in this case it is predicand to the predicative complement "my dog's favourite activity". Since there is no complement of "walked" ( usually a _by_ phrase) it is called a 'short passive'.

Comment: You walk your dog and your dog is walked by you. I don't think what you call "passive verb construction" is prevalent in English.

Comment: What non-English constructions does it usually represent? It's nothing special, just a passive gerund clause (a gerund-participial clause in BillJ's speech group). But German has many more constructions available, because it's still got inflections, and this may be some translators' tradition of "how to translate a `<insert name>` construction into English". So, as usual, when discussing language, examples are more useful than description.

Comment: 'being walked'? Who walks it?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is compiled from some of the initial comments provided:

[@BillJ says](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/364895/name-for-gerund-past-participle-combination#comment850632_364895):

> "I'm not aware of a formal name for it. Syntactically, it is 'passive
>   gerund-participial clause' functioning as subject. Like most
>   non-finite clauses, it is subjectless, and in this case it is
>   predicand to the predicative complement "my dog's favourite activity".
>   Since there is no complement of "walked" ( usually a *by* phrase) it is
>   called a 'short passive'."

[@JohnLawler says](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/364895/name-for-gerund-past-participle-combination#comment850854_364895):

> "It's nothing special, just a passive gerund clause (a
>   gerund-participial clause in BillJ's speech group). But German has
>   many more constructions available, because it's still got inflections,
>   and this may be some translators' tradition of "how to translate a
>   `<insert name>` construction into English". So, as usual, when
>   discussing language, examples are more useful than description."

Comment: @KannE I’m on a mission to clean up some of our old undeleted unanswered questions [NB: unanswered questions with *zero* score and less than 2 comments are auto-deleted after a year]. I have indeed found a few where this illustrious pair have provided comments worthy of turning into an answer. You’re welcome to join me on my mission!